# MongoDB - cannot remove multiple record from the same session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete two record from different database (practice log, student) within the same session, the problem is the practice log record is found successfully and shown in console.log(deletePracticeLog), but it cannot be remove from the database. anyone know what have I done wrong? I am very confused.

```
const deleteStudentById = async (req, res, next) => {
const sid = req.params.sid;
let deleteStudent;
let deletePracticeLog;

try {
  deleteStudent = await Students.findById(sid).populate("teacher");

} catch (err) {
const error = new HttpError("Delete failed, please try again.", 500);
return next(error);
}

try {
deletePracticeLog = await PracticeLog.find({ student: sid }).exec();
console.log(deletePracticeLog); // **<-this correctly show the record needed to be deleted, it's a object within an array**
} catch (err) {
const error = new HttpError("Cannot delete, please try again.", 500);
return next(error);
}

if (!deleteStudent) {
const error = new HttpError("Could not find student for this id.", 404);
return next(error);
}

try {
const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
sess.startTransaction();
await deleteStudent.remove({ session: sess }); //delete the student from student database
deleteStudent.teacher.students.pull(deleteStudent); //delete the student id from teacher        database
await deleteStudent.teacher.save({ session: sess });
await deletePracticeLog.remove({ session: sess }); // **<-this line caused error, when this line is removed, other code run successfully and other record are deleted.**
await sess.commitTransaction();
} catch (err) {
const error = new HttpError("Cannot delete student with provided id.", 500);
return next(error);
}

res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted student." });
};
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: when sending request to this path, the error happened at the last catch ("Cannot delete student with provided id.") @MohammadYaserAhmadi

Comment: If you get your own answer, please upvote it, tank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using `await`, you don't need to `exec()`

delete your exec() from

```
deletePracticeLog = await PracticeLog.find({ student: sid }).exec();
```

change to

```
deletePracticeLog = await PracticeLog.find({ student: sid })
```

beacuse you use exec(), use this code for remove data

```
await deletePracticeLog[0].remove({ session: sess })
```

if the result of `PracticeLog.find({ student: sid })` is one Array and you want to delete all of them, you have to use `deleteMany` like this:

```
PracticeLog.deleteMany({ student: sid }).session(sess)
```

it's worked for me

Comment: I have tried this before, it didn't work for my code, only if I delete this line then this path works, but I could not delete the practice log...

Comment: I ran your code, with deleting exec() your code is correct, please show me mongoose.connect(), I wanna see that

Comment: now the code is working! thank you! but it just deleted the first element of the practice log array, but I want to delete the whole array.

Comment: I just tried to use a for loop, and it deleted the whole array successfully, but not sure if it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227067/discussion-between-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi-and-nigel).

Comment: I updated my answer, for this situation you shouldn't use of find result, you can use `deleteMany`

Answer (score 0):

here is the Mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const studentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  email: { type: String, require: true },
  contact: { type: String, require: true },
  teacher: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "teachers" },
  practiceLogs: [
    { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "practice_logs" },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("students", studentsSchema);

const practiceLogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  repertoire: { type: String, require: true },
  student: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "students" },
  teacher: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "teachers" },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("practice_logs", practiceLogSchema);
```

here is the mongoose.connect():

```
const url =
  "myURL";

mongoose
  .connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5000);
    console.log("connected.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```